# Kafka Connect stream and Postgresql DataFileRead Slow Performance

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Connect to stream a database with 250,000,000 records. Reading from the source was no issue, it was completely read in an un-noticeable timeframe and stored on the Kafka brokers. The sink side is extremely slow though and going to take days to complete.

I'm using a JDBC Sink Connector with the following configuration:

```
"config": {
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "tasks.max": "20",
    "batch.size": "5000",
    "max.poll.records": "5000"
}
```

I'm using an aws postgres RDS instance: db.m5.4xlarge (8 cores 16vcpus 64gb ram)

The sink table has no indices other than the primary key. Using RDS performance insights, **DataFileRead** and **WALWriteLock** are consuming the vast majority of activity (DataFileRead ~60%, WalWriteLock ~30-40%).

I'm unfamiliar with database speeds and administration, is this typical performance? If not, what methods might I look into for increasing performance? Is this a case of my instance simply not being beefy enough to handle the writes?

Here is an image of the database load, the growth of the green lines near the tail-end is when I dropped all indices on the impacted sink tables.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cleared all indices other than primary key about 20 minutes prior to posting. This exponentially increased the processing time and several million rows have been processed now.